# Etiquette in summarizing comments to an answer

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, etiquette

Today I posted a question that was subsequently answered through comment conversation, some of which was removed for clarity. Subsequently for completeness, I answered my own question to summarize, making sure to acknowledge the users who contributed.

Was this correctly handled?

**Question:** *[How to change the instance of a UserControl from the containing Window's code behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61865863/how-to-change-the-instance-of-a-usercontrol-from-the-containing-windows-code-be)*

Comment: Looks fine to me. Alternatives could be putting the credits in the comments on the answer, or making the post a community wiki

Comment: You've created a good answer.  You've given credit to those that inspired the answer.  You've saved everyone else that reads the question from having to go through the comments and repeat your effort. You've changed an unanswered question into an answered question.  They each sound like something good.  — The only thing I'd fault you on is doing it so soon; it would have been better to wait at least 24 hours to give everyone in the world a chance to offer a possibly even better answer. — And tomorrow, if nothing better *does* appear, you can check your answer as accepted.

Comment: Only think I do differently in similar cases is to actually link to the comment that inspired the answer and link to the user's profile page instead of using "@Name".  the reason to link to the users name is for several reasons (1) The @ ping doesn't work in answers so the symbol is unnecessary (2) user names can change over time so by linking to the users profile and the original comment you ensure people know what you are referring too (3) duplicate names are permitted by the system so it makes it more clear who you are crediting

Comment: Thank you for the feedback all, much appreciate! Some especially useful details, @psubsee2003.

Comment: But this meta information (Kate Gregory called it *["fluff and meta talk"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KuRlLjd3700&t=303)* in the now-deleted Stack Overflow course on YouTube) does not belong in an answer. It should be in comments or be put at the end in a small font (use `<sub></sub>`). Most future readers (that is mostly from search engine hits) has zero interest in this information, and it should not be the first they see.

Comment: I would argue that giving credit is not meta info and doesn't belong in comments.  But I would agree that putting it as a footnote makes sense.